# vba buscar todos los valores 0 y mostrármelos

Tags: vba, macros

Hola soy muy nuevo en vba y tengo una duda que no me sale desde hace días. Quiero sacar todos los 0 de la columna C y que me lo muestre ya sea en un mensaje o en un `textbox`. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

     For Each c In Worksheets("Materias").Range("C2:C11").Cells
     If Abs(c.Value) = 0 Then

    MsgBox c
    End If
    Next

End Sub
```

la cosa es que lo he conseguido con este código

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
 sin embargo no es un código útil porque me sale 4 veces un mensaje `box` poniendo un 0, imagínate si tengo 500 casos además de querer poner ese resultado referenciando la columna B para saber que stock hace falta. Si no es un `Msgbox` pues en un `textbox`, lo que sea.

Comment: Por favor comparte tu código en formato de texto

Comment: Hecho, disculpa las molestias

Comment: *sin embargo no es un código útil*. ¿Y cuál sería el código útil? ¿Qué quieres conseguir? Por favor, sé más preciso preguntando

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es saber cuantos ceros hay en total en tu rango tienes que añadir una variable que sume 1 cada vez que encuentre un cero. Pon este código, que recorre todo el rango y al final te muestra un mensaje con el total de ceros encontrados:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim i As Integer

    i = 0
    For Each c In Worksheets("Materias").Range("C2:C11").Cells
        If Abs(c.Value) = 0 Then
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox "Hay un total de " & i & " ceros."

End Sub
```

Comment: Veo ahora que cada cero necesitas saber a qué dato de la columna B corresponde. Para eso tienes varias alternativas: una es que cada vez que encuentres un cero copies el valor de la celda "B" & i a una hoja o rango aparte. Otra es que ese valor de la celda B lo almacenes un array y vayas redimensionando dicho array según vayas encontrando ceros y luego pegues esos datos en una hoja o donde necesites.